# Changing the offset of div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, offset

I'm trying to create my own scroller and I have a long horizontal table contained in a div and I'm currently just trying to be able to move the div left or right.

I tried the following:

```
var d = document.getElementById("scroll");
d.style.color = "blue";
d.style.left = -300;
```

The color was to see if I could access the div from the scroll "class". It turns blue, however it's not able to offset left by 300, nothing happens.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see three issues:

1. The element is not positioned(`left`, `right`, `top` and `bottom` properties will work if the element is positioned). Alternatively, you could use `marginLeft`.
2. `-300` does not have quotes or double quotes around it.
3. You are missing the units `px`.

---

```
var d = document.getElementById("scroll");
d.style.color = "blue";
d.style.position = "relative";
d.style.left = "-300px";
```